# After upgrade to 23.04 I see the same kernel problem as others with linux-image-generic, but mine comes from ethernet-realtek-r8152. How can I fix it?

Tags: kernel, dpkg, ethernet, realtek, dkms

I rebooted with an older kernel, tried dpkg --configure -a, got this:

```
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms/1.11/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms/1.11/source/dkms.conf)
Error! The /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms/1.11/6.2.0-20-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch/config.
This indicates that it should not be built.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.20.20); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms/1.11/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms/1.11/source/dkms.conf)
Error! The /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms/1.11/6.2.0-20-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch/config.
This indicates that it should not be built.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
```

Any idea how to fix this? I'm hesitant to remove the module. I'm afraid I'll lose access to the Internet. (edit: I connect through wifi, but I have no idea what the module does.) Thanks!

Comment: The r8125 module is Realtek RTL8152/RTL8153 Based USB Ethernet Adapters. If you are not currently using one of these, I'd remove the module: `sudo apt purge oem-ethernet-realtek-r8152-lp1806322-4.15-dkms` Next, try again:  `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @chili555 Thank you! I supposed that would be the solution, but I was hesitant to try it without at least someone else suggesting it.

Comment: `dkms status` and from where did you get this package please.

Comment: dkms status is empty now, because I've removed it. The package probably came directly from Dell, as my computer has Linux factory-installed by them.

Comment: Oh dell product. No wunder I could not find the package. I think if it is dell package; only they can fix it.